# Страности с типом int в C++

Tags: c++

Начнём с того, что я ещё совсем "зелёный" в программировании. И тут на днях я баловался с С++. Написал консольную прогу, которая просто запрашивает Имя, Фамилия, Возраст, Дата рождения и выводит это на экран. "В общем, ничего нового" - как сказал бы один известный товарищ. Но вовремя тестирования я быстро нажимал клавиши и в тип int ввёл символы. Ну и естественно сразу выскочила ошибка, но прога продолжала выполнять свою работу и в конце вывела результат. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос что это может быть? Может компилятор? И да не кидайтесь тапками.

Comment: Тапками кидаться будем за то, что вы привели скрин, и совершенно не привели текст программы. "Я тут на одном средстве передвижения перемещался со скоростью 200 км/ч - так скажите, это много или мало?" На чем? Лошади, мотоцикле, самолете? Так и тут - как можно судить, что там происходило, не видя написанного вами?

Comment: это значит, что каждый символ имеет свое целочисленное значение.  int  n = 'n'; вполне нормальное присваивание

Comment: думаю, что скорее всего ввод был через `cin`,  а переменная для возраста не была инициализированна предварительно., это так, @user302113

Comment: Если это `std::cin`, то так и должно быть, это не особенность компилятора. Если `cin` не может что-то прочитать, то он не завершает программу, а переходит в своего рода "холостой режим" и игнорирует все следующие `std::cin >> my_variable;`, оставляя вас с неинициализированными переменными.

Answer (score 3):

Ничего странного тут нет: судя по всему вы использовали `cin` для ввода, так? Так вот: когда вы ввели букву вместо цифры, то `cin` выдал ошибку и перестал работать, поэтому вы не смогли ввести следующие значения. Ну а почему вывод сработал? Ну потому что вы приказали программе вывести значения переменных и она эта сделала. Она не в курсе того, что вы не поместили туда нужные вам значения - она не телепат, поэтому вывела то, что в них храниться. Ну а так, как вы не позаботились об их инициализации, там находится мусор.

Проблема, как и в 99.9% случаев не в компиляторе, а где-то между монитором и спинкой кресла.

Comment: Проблема, как и в 99.9% случаев не в компиляторе, а где-то между монитором и спинкой кресла. :D